# Codeigniter session error in Redis using PHP 7.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis

I am using CI version 3.0.3, PHP version 7.0, Redis and MariaDB. When I store session data in the Database, there are no errors. But if I switch to Redis, I get an error every time session tries to regenerate via session_regenerate_id, in my case every 300 sec. But if I refresh the page again, Redis get updated and page loads without errors.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user 
>   (path: tcp://localhost:6379?auth=xxxx)
>
> Filename: Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 625

Comment: I think you have to report this as a bug over here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues since your issue resides in the framework's system files.

Comment: As far as I can see it is introduced in PHP 7 given session_regenerate_id() is a direct PHP function/method. I have created a bug report - github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/79b8a086187f199bb708bd56477850fbf1dd9e91 for the fix on CI 3.0.3

CI 3.0.4 will ship with the update for PHP 7 out of the box.

Thanks to https://github.com/narfbg

Answer (score 0):

This is a php / memcached bug [related](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71187).

Work around:

```
class MemcachedSession extends SessionHandler { public function read($session_id) { return (string)parent::read($session_id); } }

$sess = new MemcachedSession(); session_set_save_handler($sess, true);

session_start(); $_SESSION['value'] = session_id(); session_regenerate_id(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to build a CI solutions based on above. I cat not directly edit CI core since it will neither be practical nor a good practice. Hopefully new PHP update release will address this soon.